# методы программного выполнения прокрутки listview android

Tags: android, listview, прокрутка

Какие сущетвуют методы программного выполнения прокрутки listview android?

Comment: По ссылке на документацию есть всё https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#smoothScrollByOffset(int)

Comment: # kerradus, спасибо.